# Authentication with AngularJs and Devise Rails, Do I need token system?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, angularjs, devise

I am creating an application based on Rails and AngularJS. I would like to implement an authentication system by using gem Devise.
I am wondering how to do it. I read some articles about attribute :token_authenticatable : I will have to put my token at the end of all requests I will send.

I have also read this demo project https://github.com/sectore/CafeTownsend-Angular-Rails
They have implemented a SessionService which can create and delete server session. (I suppose, I can use Devise for this job). In rails controler, they get session[:user_id] to know if user is authenticated or not...

My question : Do I need a token system or a cookies system to authenticated my requests ?

Thanks

Comment: Is this question about AngularJS or Devise? I've done both token- and cookie-based auth with AngularJS and it looks like Devise supports both (via Token Authenticatable and Rememberable).

Comment: My question is about how to design a good authentication system when I use angularjs with rails as API. If both solutions are supported, I don't know. Maybe the cookie-based one is easier to implemented

Comment: Cookies are easier because the browser sends them automatically with each request. If you plan on supporting non-browser clients, you should go with token passed in HTTP headers - check out $http.defaults.headers.common to inject your token header for all $http requests.

Comment: Yes, of course, I did not consider that browser sends cookies automatically, so it's transparent for me. Perfect in this case. Thanks

Comment: To give a feedback: I have finally chosen token system because session_id was not sent for POST request. Token system is a bit more tricky to implement but now I know exactly what happen.

Comment: take a look at this railscasts http://railscasts.com/episodes/352-securing-an-api it may help you

Answer (score 6):

If your server will be on the **same domain as your client**, ie: will only be expecting request from your angular client, and the client is hosted on the same URL as the server, then you should use cookies over ssl (for simplicity), EG:

Your site:

```
www.myangularsite.com/somepage
```

Your Server

```
www.myangularsite.com/someserverfunction
```

They both have the same domain.

However, if you plan on having your server side **on a different URL**, maybe as an API, then go with tokens, EG:

Your site:

```
www.myangularsite.com/somepage
```

Your Server

```
api.myangularsite.com/someserverfunction
or
myrubyapi.com/someserverfunction
```

The URL domain is different.